# How can we copy the column data of one DataTable to another, even if there are different column names between DataTables?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, copy

I have two DataTables. 
First is

```
DataTable NameAddressPhones = new DataTable();
```

with Three columns **Name, Address and PhoneNo**.But I only want two columns **Name and Address** data so I want to copy those columns (with data) to the new DataTable.

```
DataTable NameAddress = new DataTable();
```

For that I do

```
            foreach (DataRow sourcerow in NameAddressPhones.Rows)
            {
                DataRow destRow = NameAddress.NewRow();
                foreach (string colname in columns)
                {
                    destRow[colname] = sourcerow[colname];
                }
                NameAddress.Rows.Add(destRow);
            }
```

I clear the NameAddressPhones(first) DataTable every time there are new records inserted in the table. And every time there will be the same number of columns but the column names will be different like **Nm** instead of **Name, Add** instead of **Address**.Now the problem is the second DataTable already has column names **Name and Address** and now I want to copy the columns data of **Nm and Add** to the second DataTable but the column names are different than the column names of the second DataTable. So even if there are different column names I want to copy **Nm** column data of first DataTable to the column **Name** of second DataTable and column **Add** data of first DataTable to column **Address** of second DataTable.

In short how can we copy column data from one DataTable to another even if there are different column names of both DataTables like **Nm** is the column name of first DataTable and **Name** is the column name of second DataTable then the data of the column **Nm** should be copied to the column **Name**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the simplest way:

```
foreach (DataRow sourcerow in NameAdressPhones.Rows)
{
    DataRow destRow = NameAdress.NewRow();
    destRow["Name"] = sourcerow["Nm"];
    destRow["Address"] = sourcerow["Add"];
    NameAdress.Rows.Add(destRow);
}
```

Automation is great when it's available.  When it's not, you have to map source columns to destination columns in some manner.

If the columns are in the same order in both tables, you *could* just reference the values by ordinal instead of column name, but that's such a bad idea I'm not even going to post any code for it.

Comment: @MusiGenesis,Thanks...Great..I have not just thought like that.But sir how can I map the columns ?

Comment: If you use my code sample, that's the map. If you want to get fancy and maintain a bunch of lists somewhere of column mappings, you can, but you're probably just making more work for yourself.

Comment: There is not fixed order of column every time.Like column Nm once may have index number of 0 then next time it may be at position 2 in the table.Then will it work ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: rules are meant to be broken, but not this one. NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER reference columns by their index, since column orderings in the underlying database (or in the SELECT query) can easily change.

Comment: Does it mean reference the columns by its name then there will not be any problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Use column index number rather than names:

```
destRow[0] = sourcerow[0]; // for column 0 = "Name" or "NM"
```

Comment: @SeaDrive, But there is not fixed  index of the columns.Like column Nm will be at position 0 or not.

Comment: You have to have some way of knowing which columns you want, i.e. something to keep you from putting the address in the name column. However you know that, it shouldn't be too hard to cope using either ordinals, or string variables as the index.

n1 = "Name";
n2 = "Nm" ;

// later

destRow[n1] = sourceRow[n2] ;

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right, then the way this is usually done is by using stored procedures. You have the same stored procedures in both databases, but the implementation is specific to the table schema of each database. This allows you the abstraction you need.