# Fastest way to merge set of data to another set with an expression

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I am trying to use C# and copy a data structure from :

**PersonId, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip**

into

**PersonId, Name = FirstName + " " + LastName, + Address= Address + " " +  City + " " +  State + " " +  Zip**

The into section will be dynamic based on user input so I would like to know the best and most efficient way to do something like this. I tried to do this with datatables but it doesn't seem like it's possible to create an expression from one datatable that is used in another table. I have to do this within C#. I am taking a CSV file putting it datatable and allowing the user to manipulate the mappings and then pushing those results into a datatable  so it that can be exported.

Any thoughts on this issue?

TIA
Paul

Comment: What are the data structures in?  Their own classes?  Do they have to be in datatables to start and end with?

Comment: They are currently datatables. Yes, as the structures can be different based on the user's input.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make strings. But I'm not sure how I would use string.format on a large set of data when I would have to iterate through each record.

Comment: Can you post the code you've attempted that isn't working?  Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592637/how-can-we-copy-the-column-data-of-one-datatable-to-another-even-if-there-is-dif?rq=1

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. I don't understand what you mean when you say `The into section will be dynamic based on user input`. Do you just mean the values of PersonId, FirstName, etc. will be different? Are you just parsing a CSV?

Comment: The code is different, as I want to take the data in table1 and create expressions from table1 to insert into table2. IE: Name = FirstName + " " + LastName

Comment: I am taking a CSV file and allowing the user to manipulate the results of that CSV prior to inserting into a final datatable that can be exported.

Comment: Please try  to update your post with information you've added in comments. While it may not be enough to make question answerable it definitely will make it better.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be creating SQL VIEWS which when queried returns personID and Name. In this way you just need to query the view and it will return dynamic results. However if the base table is large then performance might be impacted.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I will not be able to use SQL to do this. I need to perform this with c#